# End Event on Room Resource calendar

Tags: exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2013

The problem that I face: I currently use a product that displays calendar items on an iPad outside of conference rooms. I have all the room resources set up and everything works brilliantly except if I try to end the event early from this display.

The reason it doesn't end: When User A schedules a meeting and adds the room Conference Room as a resource, and Conference Room accepts, the meeting is still owned by the organizer, or in this case User A. Because of this, the room itself can not edit times on an event, only the organizer can.

The question: Is there any way, to have the Room auto accept the meeting, and also be able to edit the event?

Please note, I have tried this with Exchange 2007, Exchange 2010, Exchange 2013, and Office 365. The servers have been both on-premises and hosted.

Answer (score 1):

No the only valid editor of a Meeting is the organizer for the reason that each copy of the meeting stored in the Attendees mailboxes is a separate item in the Exchange Mailstore. Eg Even if the Organizer modifies the appointment and doesn't send out Meeting updates the changes they make won't show on the attendees (or Room Mailbox) calendar until the updates are sent and accepted. This is fundamental to the way in which Appointments work if you need to change a meeting for some reason you may want to look at impersonating the Owner of the Appointment in EWS. The one thing the Room mailbox (or any attendee) could do is propose a new meeting time which would be a separate message that would sent back to the Organizer who then once they accepted would send out a normal Meeting update to all attendees.

Cheers
Glen